# How can I find out the original username a process was started with?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, process, solaris

There is a perl script that needs to run as root but we must make sure the user who runs the script did not log-in originally as user 'foo' as it will be removed during the script.

So how can I find out if the user, who might have su-ed several times since she logged in has not impersonated 'foo' at any time in that chain?

I found an interesting perl script that was calling the following two shell scripts, but I think that would only work on Solaris.

```
my $shell_parent = 
`ps -ef | grep -v grep | awk \'{print \$2\" \"\$3}\' | egrep \"^@_\" | awk \'{print \$2}'`;

my $parent_owner = 
`ps -ef | grep -v grep | awk \'{print \$1\" \"\$2}\' | grep @_ | awk \'{print \$1}\'`;
```

This needs to work on both Linux and Solaris and I'd rather eliminate the repeated calls to he the shell and keep the whole thing in Perl.

Comment: Process table stuff is horribly unportable and most of the CPAN stuff that does it shells out to `ps` anyway. I could write code to do the job without shelling out on Linux, but I don't have the knowledge to do the same on Solaris (or a Solaris box handy)

Comment: Blarg, Solaris has a nice, tidy, discoverable `/proc`, but the interface is all binary structures defined in system header files.

Comment: @hobbs: http://search.cpan.org/~durist/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45/ looks solid enough

Comment: @Hasturkun: I just tried Proc::ProcessTable and the results are truncated )-:

Comment: @hippietrail: Truncated how? and on what OS?

Comment: @Hasturkun: On Solaris (as this question is tagged). The process I need to monitor is a perl script with annoyingly long args. Solaris has a hard limit on the length of this info from what I have read, even if you use the procfs directly.

Comment: @hippietrail: In that case I doubt much can be done (although from what I see from `struct psinfo`, it _might_ be possible to get the address for argv, read it from the process' memory, though I couldn't really recommend that)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty and (UNIX only):

```
my $user = (split /\s/,`who am i`)[0];
```

The `who am i` command returns the owner of the TTY - i.e. who you were when you logged in.

If you want to do this in pure perl:

```
use POSIX;
my $tty = POSIX::ttyname(1); # The tty we are running in
my $uid = (stat $tty)[4];    # The owner uid of that tty
my $user = getpwuid($uid);   # The user with that uid
```

This will return the correct user, even after multiple su's. This usually freaks out your (less experienced) sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl program that checks for direct setuid change:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

sub callingUser() {
    my ($login, $pass, $uid, $gid) = getpwuid($<);
    return $login;
}

sub effectiveUser() {
    my ($login, $pass, $uid, $gid) = getpwuid($>);
    return $login;
}

printf("Real user name: %s\n", effectiveUser());
printf("Calling user name: %s\n", callingUser());
```

But since you mentioned that the setuid change may have occured anytime before, you probably have to parse the output of `ps`: I would do it using the following command. This command only uses features defined in [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ps.html), so I hope it is portable to all kinds of systems:

```
ps -e -o pid,ppid,user,ruser
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is what you want. The function `hasBeenUser` reads the process table and then follows the process chain from the current process down the parent process. If any of the processes on the way has a `user` or `real user` field equal to the username in question, the function returns a nonzero value.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

sub hasBeenUser($) {
        my ($username) = @_;

        my $procs = {};
        open(PS, "ps -e -o pid,ppid,user,ruser |") or die;
        while (defined(my $line = <PS>)) {
                next unless $line =~ m"^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+$";
                my ($pid, $ppid, $user, $ruser) = (int($1), int($2), $3, $4);
                $procs->{$pid} = [$pid, $ppid, $user, $ruser];
        }
        close(PS) or die;

        my $pid = $$;
        while (exists($procs->{$pid})) {
                my $proc = $procs->{$pid};
                delete $procs->{$pid}; # don't risk ending in an endless loop.
                warn "D: checking process $pid\n";
                if ($proc->[2] eq $username || $proc[3] eq $username) {
                        warn "E: process $pid was called by $username.\n";
                        return 1;
                }
                last if $pid < 2;
                $pid = $proc->[1];
        }
        return 0;
}

hasBeenUser("del"); # should return 0
hasBeenUser("root"); # should return nonzero
```

Comment: Is there a java equivalent of the same ?

Comment: Yes, spawning a subprocess and reading its output can be done with Java as well.

Comment: Can you please provide some example for the same?

Comment: It doesn't fit into a comment. You could ask a new question referring to this question. But this idea will only work on POSIX systems, not of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I recognized a corner case when calling scripts from mc (at least in our RHEL's), which results that the `who am i` does not output anything. To circumvent that, I produced the following one-liner in bash:

```
REALUSERNAME=$(ps uhp `ps -AjH | grep \`ps -u $USER fh | awk '{ print $0; if(index($0, "ps -u $USER fh")) exit 0;}' | tac | awk '{if(!index($0, "\\\\\_")){print $1; exit 0;}}'\` | awk '{print $3}'` | awk '{print $1}')
```

Essentially, this walks backwards on the tree output of `ps -u $USER fh` and then crops on the topmost username column.

Thoughts, better solutions are welcome :-)