# java How can I find out the original username a process was started with?

Tags: java

How would I get to know the real/ogiginal username ?

On linux, we can run the below command, which would give the real user name based on the link but what is the java equivalent of the same ?

```
REALUSERNAME=$(ps uhp `ps -AjH | grep \`ps -u $USER fh | awk '{ print $0; if(index($0, "ps -u $USER fh")) exit 0;}' | tac | awk '{if(!index($0, "\\\\\_")){print $1; exit 0;}}'\` | awk '{print $3}'` | awk '{print $1}')
```

[How can I find out the original username a process was started with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441939/how-can-i-find-out-the-original-username-a-process-was-started-with)

Comment: you want to find the logged in user ? or the person who started the application

Comment: The person who started the application